# Button Type "Reset" is not working fine with extjs 3.3.0 returning this.ownerct.getform is not a function

Tags: extjs

During migration from ext2.2.1 to ext 3.3.0, we faced issue with reset
       functionality. It is not reseting the form and throwing this.ownerct.getform is not 
       a function in mozilla firefox. In internet, its throwing "object doesn't support 
       this property or method". Can somebody help in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.ownerCt.ownerCt.getform()
```